# Posting Badge Information to Chatter

Tags: apex, chatter, feeditem, chatter-feed

I'm trying to do a `Thanks` post via `Apex`. More specifically, I want it like this : [image]

These are the steps I have taken to be able to post a `Badge`.

```
1. Created a WorkBadgeDefinition Object
2. Connected the WorkBadgeDefinition object to a WorkBadge object
3. Connected the WorkBadge Object to the WorkThanks object
4. Connected the WorkThanks object to a FeedItem object
```

After step 4, it does post on chatter, however, does not contain the link to the badge. Though `FeedItem` has a related record of a `WorkThanks` object, it does not specify the badge being given.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong and/or missing? For the steps, I followed the following schema https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_badge.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For everyone confused on how to post a `Thanks` on `Chatter` WITH the `Badge Attachment` -- all you need to do is set the `Type` to `RypplePost` on the `FeedItem` and automatically the chatter post will display the badge information.